# History of $p$-adic numbers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, math-history, p-adic-number-theory

I'm interested in learning about the historical motivation and development of $p$-adic numbers. I haven't been able to find any books on the topic. I'd appreciate any references, including to more general history books which include coverage of the $p$-adics. Alternatively, if anyone has any knowledge about the history of $p$-adic numbers, feel free to post a summary here, particularly if you can highlight any names, papers and keywords that I could use to do more research on my own.

I'm not looking for a simplified overview, I want to really dig into the details, but any amount of information that could get me started is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One useful starting point is Peter Roquette's [History of Valuation Theory.](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Eroquette/hist_val.pdf) This may be a bit more general than you seek, but it has a bibliography that should provel helpful locating other sources. See also F. Gouvea, [Hensel’s p-adic Numbers: early history,](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Epanchish/Mag2009L3/GouveaHensel2.pdf) and the following

Ullrich, Peter, 1998: [The genesis of Hensels p-adic numbers.](https://doi.org/10.1484/M.STHS-EB.4.2017037)
In the book:  $ $ P. L. Butzer, H.Th.
Jongen,W. Oberschelp (edd.), Charlemagne and his Heritage. 1200 Years of
Civilization and Science in Europe. / Karl der Große und sein Nachwirken.
1200 Jahre Kultur und Wissenschaft in Europa. Vol. 2. Mathematical Arts.
Thurnhout: Brepols, 163-178

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand that last reference - is "Charlemagne and his Heritage" the name of a book which includes a paper called "The genesis of Hensel's p-adic Numbers"?

Comment: @JackM Yes, see "In: ..." Edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: @Torsten Thanks. The links have been refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

[This post is an attempt to inform others on an interesting finding in Gauss's Nachlass; I know math stack exchange format is intended primarily for more "closed" answers, but I felt like it is my duty to acknowledge interested readers on this finding. This question looks seeks for an historical survey of the development p-adic numbers, while my answer focuses on its prehistory.]

In a recently scanned notebook of Gauss (Schaede 5), one can find a note whose title is "Congruentia infinita", which includes the following results (a pic of the relavent page is shown at the end of this answer):

> Congruentia infinita $$x^5-20x^4-86x^3-98x^2+80x+3\equiv 0 \pmod {241^{\infty}}$$ has roots: $$(1) = 2+191.r+$$ $$(2) = 3+$$ $$(3) = 4+$$ $$(4) = 5+$$ $$(5) = 6+$$

and in the bottom of this page Gauss also writes:

> $$\sqrt{5}\pmod{11^{\infty}}= 9.0.4.10.4.4$$

The last result is about the last digits of the square root of 5 calculated 11-adically, and according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4611125/how-do-i-differentiate-between-sqrt5-and-sqrt5-in-the-11-adics-an), this result is actually correct (he apparently needed this square root in order to calculate the 11-adic expansion of the fifth root of unity). These results show that Gauss almost certainly preconceived of the p-adic numbers, since he used such expressions as $\pmod {11^{\infty}}$. It must be mentioned that since Kurt Hensel's first publication on this number system appeared only in 1897, the fact that Gauss anticipated it somehow escaped the attention of the editors of Gauss's collected works, so they did not publish this important fragment.

In the recent literature on the history of p-adic numbers, I found two references that "suspect" that Gauss had something similar to p-adic analysis in his arsenal:

- The article "**on the origin of p-adic analysis**" by Peter Ulrich, which mentions Gauss's proof of his lemma on polynomials (from article 42 of the D.A) using valuation theory as part of the prehistory of p-adic analysis.
- The article "**The Unpublished Section Eight: On the Way to Function Fields
  over a Finite Field**" by Gunther Frei, which observes that Gauss discovered and proved an early version of Hensel's lemma, and makes the following speculation:

> It looks almost as if Gauss thought of some kind of algebraic closure of finite fields or some kind of p-adic version of the complex numbers. Unfortunately he did not leave us more details of these ideas than what he started to treat in the §§ 373–375 of the Disquisitiones generales de congruentiis.  After entry 80, Gauss occasionally continued to work on higher reciprocity laws, on the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra and on the theory of cyclotomy, but he never came back to the theory of polynomials over a finite field.

I noticed several things about Gauss's attempt to find the five roots of the quintic polynomial $\pmod {241^{\infty}}$:

- The first parts of the five roots all satisfy the polynomial $\pmod {241^1}$. It  also seems interesting that in this particular example considered by Gauss, the five roots are $2,3,4,5,6$.
- For the first root, Gauss also uses the term $191.r$ (I believe $r$ is a abbreviation for "reminder").

[image]

Goettingen State and University Library, Cod. Ms. Gauß Schedae 5, p. 14.

Comment: This is very interesting. The initial part of the $11$-adic expansion of $\sqrt{5}$ is also in the middle of the page with a few other expansions, which I don't recognize. It would be interesting to figure out what the five (presumable) $11$-adic expansions are on the bottom of the page below the $11$-adic expansion of $\sqrt{5}$.